# sed not working properly with multiple input files

Tags: sed, zsh

`sed -i` is creating a backup of all files in subdirectories before editing in place (as expected) but it's not actually editing files in subdirectories.

```
$ mkdir -p a/b
$ echo "A" > a/a.txt
$ echo "B" > a/b/b.txt
```

Now I have two text files, one in `a` one in a subdirectory of `a`

```
$ sed -i.bac "1s/^/PREPENDED /" a/**/*.txt
```

Backups are created for both:

```
$ find a  
a
a/a.txt
a/a.txt.bac
a/b
a/b/b.txt
a/b/b.txt.bac
```

Only a.txt is edited:

```
$ cat a/a.txt   
PREPENDED A

$ cat a/b/b.txt 
B
```

I'm using ZSH (so I have globstar support) and I'm on Mac.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why did you tag the question [tag:bash] if you're using zsh?

Comment: Bash 4 has globstar support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are needing to descend through several levels of directories, a single invocation of `sed` alone is not sufficient. However, using `find` you can accomplish what you want in a single line. If you are not familiar with `find ... -exec '{}' \;` it is worth taking a few minutes with [**startpage.com**](http://startpage.com) and do a quick search. In your case, the following invocation works well:

```
find a -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bac 's/^/PREPENDED /' '{}' \;
```

Here `find` searches directory `a` and all below for any file (`-type f`) matching `*.txt`, then for each file (indicated by `'{}'`) `-exec` executes `sed -i.bac 's/^/PREPENDED /'` and lastly an escaped `\;` is given to indicate the end of the `-exec` command.

results:

```
$ ls -1 a
b
a.txt
a.txt.bac

$ ls -1 a/b
b.txt
b.txt.bac

$ cat a/a.txt
PREPENDED A

$ cat a/b/b.txt
PREPENDED B
```

As was correctly pointed out, with globstar set `shopt -s globstar` it is unnecessary to use `find` as the following invocation of `sed` is sufficient:

```
 sed -i.bac 's/^/PREPENDED /' a/**/*.txt
```

Comment: globstar handles descending directories; there is no need to invoke `find`.

Comment: Accepted for the globstar based answer. All I needed was to remove the `1`

Comment: @Jake: That only works if all your input files have exactly 1 line. If that's the case, please update your question to state that.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, my files are more than one line. The `find` based solution works.

Answer (score 4):

It's happening because your sed invocation only has a single line 1, which happens to be in `a.txt`. If you want it to do it for each file then you need to invoke sed multiple times.

```
for f in a/**/*.txt
do
  sed ... "$f"
done
```

Comment: +1; to put it differently: `sed` _invariably_ counts line numbers _cumulatively, across all input files_, so address `1` matches the first line in the _very first input file only_ (contrast with `awk`, which, in addition to the cumulative `NR` counter, provides a `FNR` counter for per-input-file line numbers).